# Detect SHARE in QB64

Tags: qb64

Am currently using the following code to detect share in qb64:

Is there an easier way to detect share?

```
REM detect share in qb64:
InregsX.AX = &H1000
CALL INTERRUPTX(&H2F, InregsX, OutregsX)
IF (OutregsX.AX AND &HFF) = &HFF THEN
    Share.Installed = True
ELSE
    Share.Installed = False
END IF
```

Comment: Share.exe is a dos driver which loads the share processor.

Comment: You mean to check whether the driver is installed or not? That's the only way I could find that is documented, and even that isn't 100% reliable due to differences in DOS implementations (see [Int 2F/AX=1000h](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/00/43.html))

Comment: [AX=1001h](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/01/43.html) may also be relevant, depending on what you're doing, but it would seem AX=1000h is the best choice for just detecting whether the driver is loaded or not.

Comment: Just trying to detect share so I can lock/unlock file records during permission denied with multi-nodes.